# How can I add a dynamic date column on Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi

I have a question on Power BI, basically i have a column with date (HIREDATE), and my task is to add a column that calculate the difference between the ACTUAL date and the date on my column. So it needs to be dynamic.
I watched some youtube videos but haven't found a case like mine, even though i think it's a common, not very rare task.
Following a tutorial on Youtube and on Microsoft WebSite I added a custom column named Experience with the following code :

```
= Duration.ToRecord ( YEAR(TODAY()) - [#"Date d'embauche"]) /* Date d'embauche = HIREDATE in french*/
```

It shows me :

[No syntax errors have detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTlPR.png)

But when I click on

> OK

It shows me this :

> Expression.Error: The name 'YEAR' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably you are adding the Custom column in Power Query. I would rather recommend to add a Calculated Column through the following DAX expression:

Date difference =
YEAR (
TODAY ()
)
- YEAR ( 'Table Name'[HIREDATE] )

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked.
Yes I was trying to do it on Poqer Query, but I added a calculated column as you said, and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Power Query you would need DateTime.FixedLocalNow() to get the date time, then wrap that function with Date.Year to extract the year, so you would have the following:

```
Date.Year(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) - Date.Year([#"Date d'embauche"])
```

in this example, the formula is used in a custom column, to give the time difference in years.

[image]

Normally it is best to do these sort of transformations in Power Query before getting to the data model.